# datepicker deshabilitar 5 días antes de una fecha dada

Tags: php, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

necesito deshabilitar de un calendario 5 días antes de una fecha dada.  El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<input type="text" name="fecha_interconsulta" id="fecha_interconsulta" size="12" tabindex="4" maxlength="10" class="iconocal datepicker" value="<?php echo $fecha_hoy; ?>" />
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    //OPCIONES EN https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html
                    startDate:"-30d",
                    endDate:"0",
                    assumeNearbyYear: true,
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                    language: "es",
                    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "1,2,3,4,5",
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    autoclose: true,
                    clearBtn:false,
                    todayBtn:false,
                    todayHighlight:true,
     beforeShow : function(){
            var dateTime = new Date('<?php echo $fecha_valida;?>');
            // hacer algo acá al medio
                $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "-5" );

        } 
    });
```

Comment: Y que sucede????? No te lo deshabilita???

Comment: no lo deshabilita

Comment: que libreria exacta de datetime estas usando???

Comment: bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Intenta con minDate: moment(new Date('<?php echo $fecha_valida;?>')).subtract("5","d") pero dentro de las opciones, no en el metodo beforeShow

Comment: alguna solución sin la librería moment?

Comment: crea una variable antes de llamar a .datepicker y pon var date = new Date('<?php echo $fecha_valida;?>'); luego abajo date.setDate(date.getDate()-5); y ya dentro del datepicker le pones minDate: date,

Comment: lo intenté y no funcionó es posible que hagas un jsfiddle?